# Filtering Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to filter my Eloquent model collections based on if a user has access to the model or not.

My current method works, but it is really slow so I am wondering if there is a more performant way to do it?

I have a `userHasAccess()` method on every model in the collection.
It uses Laravel's ACL Features to determine if the user has access to the model:

```
public function userHasAccess()
{
    if (Auth::user()->can('show', $this)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I then override the `newCollection()` method on the model:

```
public function newCollection(array $models = Array())
{
    $collection = new Collection($models);

    $collection = $collection->filter(function($model)
    {
        if($model->userHasAccess())
            return true;
    });

    return $collection;
}
```

The policy method looks like this:

```
public function show(User $user, Quote $quote)
{
    if(!$quote->customer)
        return false;

    if(($user->id === $quote->user_id))
        return true;

    if($user->hasRole(['super-admin','admin']))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Especially in terms of performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the logic to the query and speed it up dramatically

```
$query = User::query();

if(!Auth::user()->hasRole(['super-admin','admin'])){
    $query->where('user_id','=',Auth::id);
}

$data = $query->get();
```

You could do this on a wider scale using a scope

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function scopeLimitByUser($query)
    {
        if(!Auth::user()->hasRole(['super-admin','admin'])){
            $query->where('user_id','=',Auth::id);
        }
    }
}
```

Then for the quote customer you can add a where to the query

```
$query->whereNotNull('customer_id');
```

Comment: Thanks - I ended up doing something similar, so thank you for confirming my direction. I also like the idea of using a query scope.